# Navigation between several modal dynamic forms

Tags: delphi

My application has a main menu which has 4 buttons.
Each button creates a dynamic form using:

```
procedure OpenForm1;
begin 
  frmForm1 := TfrmForm1.Create(Application);
  try
    frmForm1.ShowModal;
  finally
    frmForm1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Each dynamic form has 4 buttons to navigate between each other dynamic forms.
when clicking button:

```
frmForm1.ModalResult:= mrOk;
OpenForm2; //Which is the same code than for OpenForm1
```

I use the same for the other forms, exept for get back to main menu:

```
frmFormx.ModalResult:= mrOK;
frmMain.Show;
```

The navigation between dynamic forms seems good but the non active ones are still in memory.

How can I release the not in use forms?

Thanks for help.